# Why can't I use attr_accessor inside initialize?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eval

I'm trying to do an `instance_eval` followed by a `attr_accessor` inside `initialize`, and I keep getting this: ``initialize': undefined method 'attr_accessor'`. Why isn't this working?

The code looks kind of like this:

```
class MyClass
   def initialize(*args)
      instance_eval "attr_accessor :#{sym}"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't call attr_accessor on the instance, because attr_accessor is not defined as an instance method of MyClass. It's only available on modules and classes. I suspect you want to call attr_accessor on the instance's metaclass, like this:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(varname)
    class <<self
      self
    end.class_eval do
      attr_accessor varname
    end
  end
end

o1 = MyClass.new(:foo)
o2 = MyClass.new(:bar)
o1.foo = "foo" # works
o2.bar = "bar" # works
o2.foo = "baz" # does not work
```

Comment: class_eval is the same as putting it where you wrote self

Comment: No, it's not. `class <<self; ...;end` is not a closure. You wouldn't be able to access `varname` inside it, but you can access it in the `class_eval` block.

Comment: [semiomant's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14978624/403664) is good. check it out.

Answer (score 5):

A cleaner implementation (**NB: This will add the accessor to ALL instances of the class, not just the single instance, see comments below**):

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(varname)
    self.class.send(:attr_accessor, varname)
  end
end
```

Comment: This defines the accessor as an instance method of `MyClass`. So if you have `o1 = MyClass.new(:foo)` and `o2 = MyClass.new(:bar)` both `o1` and `o2` have accessors for both `foo` and `bar`, which is not the intended behavior.

Comment: Quite right!  Here have my upboats. I'll leave this answer here (with your comment) for any who may come across it.

Comment: Rob's solution looks way much cleaner. But I will stick to sepp2k's solution, having the accessors only for one instance.

Answer (score 5):

Rob d'Apice has it **almost** right. You just need to write:

```
self.singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, varname)
```

or

```
self.singleton_class.class_eval "attr_accessor :#{varname}"
```

or my favorite variant

```
self.singleton_class.class_exec do attr_accessor varname end
```

assuming the value of `varname` is a symbol