# Can't access ActiveModel::Serialized attribute from views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

Trying to fetch some products from this API - but I can't seem to access my ActiveModel::Serialized attribute `product.name` from my views. Where did I go wrong?

Model:

```
require 'rest_client'

class ThirdPartyProducts
    include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

    # Not setting attributes here as there's just too many in the JSON response
    # attr_accessor :lorem, :ipsum, :dolor, :sit, :amet

    def attributes=(hash)
      hash.each do |key, value|

        # Set attributes here instead
        # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734984/why-cant-i-use-attr-accessor-inside-initialize

        self.class.send(:attr_accessor, "#{key}")
        send("#{key}=", value)
      end
    end

    def self.fetch
      response = RestClient.get "http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=uid7849-6112293-28&format=json&fts=women"
      raw_products = JSON.parse(response)["products"]

      raw_products.map do |product|
        what_to_name_this ||= self.new
        product = what_to_name_this.from_json(product.to_json)

        name = product.name
        # url = ...
        # image = ...
      end
    end
end
```

Controller:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = ThirdPartyProducts.fetch
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% if @products.any? %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="product">
      <%= product.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError in Main#index
Showing /root/rails-repo/app/views/main/index.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `name' for "McQ Alexander McQueen Mesh-paneled stretch-jersey top":String
Extracted source (around line #5):
  <% if @products.any? %>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="product">
        <%= product.name %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %> 

Rails.root: /root/rails-repo

app/views/main/index.html.erb:5:in `block in _app_views_main_index_html_erb__1422808888741532498_21926060'
app/views/main/index.html.erb:3:in `each'
app/views/main/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_main_index_html_erb__1422808888741532498_21926060'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming third party products to be an array of products you might want to redefine your class in something like:

```
class ThirdPartyProducts
  require 'rest_client'

  def self.fetch
    response = RestClient.get "http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=uid7849-6112293-28&format=json&fts=women"
    raw_products = JSON.parse(response)["products"]
    products = []
    raw_products.map { |pro| Product.new(pro) }
  end
end
```

And:

```
class Product
   def new(args)
     hash.each do |key, value| 
       self.class.send(:attr_accessor, "#{key}") }
       send("#{key}=", value)
     end
   end
end
```

With this the line:

```
@products = ThirdPartyProducts.fetch
```

Is returning an array of `Product` instances each with the response of the api.

As the array exists you don't need anymore:

```
<% if @products.any? %>
```

`@products.any` is always and array, and if empty the iteration will not render the next lines so you don't have any logic in the view.

Updated answer:

Other option is using a hash in the view for each element.

```
@products = Products.fetch

class Products
  def self.fetch
    response = RestClient.get "http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=uid7849-6112293-28&format=json&fts=women"
    JSON.parse(response)["products"]
  end
end
```

And in the views:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= product["name"] %>
   <%= product["price"] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! Quick questions though: 1) The ShopSense JSON response is a mix of arrays and hashes, I've added an example to https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/11058955 - does that change anything? 2) Basically I'm trying to parse it for product name, URL and image 3) Don't I need `include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON` anymore?

Comment: Doensn't change anything. JSON.parse will return a hash of hashes and arrays. You just need to ask for the array of hashes containing the products, and then iterate over each elemento creating a new product object. This way you can access it from the views using #attribute. Anyway you also can reuse the same hash if you don't want to create objects for each element. See updated answer.

Comment: ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON was used to convert to json in the model the previously parsed hash. So no, my guess is that you don't need it.

Comment: Awesome! Please hold as I implement.

Comment: I had a typo, in the define attributes. After that I the runnable app is not working. Anyway if you just need 3 attributs. Instead of use a dynamic definer, set the attributes with attr_accesor in the product class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58631/discussion-between-jorge-de-los-santos-and-mark-boulder).

Comment: Sure men, find me in tebayoso@gmail.com